# USG Command not found on Ubuntu Server 22.04 (Ubuntu Security Guide)

Tags: 22.04

I am attempting to run the Ubuntu Security Guide in BASH.  When running , I get a command not found error message.  When I run `pro status --all` I see usg is enabled:

```
erik@beef-test:~$ pro status --all
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS       DESCRIPTION
anbox-cloud      yes       disabled     Scalable Android in the cloud
cc-eal           yes       n/a          Common Criteria EAL2 Provisioning Packages
esm-apps         yes       enabled      Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled      Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
fips             yes       n/a          NIST-certified FIPS crypto packages
fips-preview     yes       disabled     Preview of FIPS crypto packages undergoing certification with NIST
fips-updates     yes       disabled     FIPS compliant crypto packages with stable security updates
livepatch        yes       enabled      Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel  yes       disabled     Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated
├ generic        yes       disabled     Generic version of the RT kernel (default)
└ intel-iotg     yes       disabled     RT kernel optimized for Intel IOTG platform
ros              yes       n/a          Security Updates for the Robot Operating System
ros-updates      yes       n/a          All Updates for the Robot Operating System
usg              yes       enabled      Security compliance and audit tools
```

I ran `sudo find / -name usg` and the usg binary is not found.

Answer (score 0):

USG package was not installed.  I installed the package and am in business.
[Results of apt cache command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EB0d.png)